# minio on AKS - unable to mount the volume

Tags: devops, azure-aks, minio

I am trying to spin minio pods on AKS service, the pod runs for keeps crashing, here are the detailed logs:

Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 0s)
Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 0s)
Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 0s)
Waiting for a minimum of 2 disks to come online (elapsed 2s)
Waiting for all other servers to be online to format the disks.
Unable to connect to http://minio-1.minio.default.svc.cluster.local:9000/data: volume not found
Unable to connect to http://minio-2.minio.default.svc.cluster.local:9000/data: volume not found
Unable to connect to http://minio-3.minio.default.svc.cluster.local:9000/data: Post http://minio-3.minio.default.svc.cluster.local:9000/minio/storage/v8/data/getinstanceid?: dial tcp: lookup minio-3.minio.default.svc.cluster.local on 10.0.0.10:53: no such host

I suspected this is due to the Volumes that I attached, I was using Azure_Managed_Disk as it does not support multiple **readWriteMany** I am using **Azure_Files** now but still, I am getting the same error.

my deployment file:

[image]

Any leads on this will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: How do you create the PVC? Can you share the YAML file?

Comment: Yes sure, 
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azdisk-minio1
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: "azdisk-minio1"

Comment: It seems no problem. How about the SC? You'd better add the details in the question. It's more suitable.